# Playground import - No such module after updating to Xcode 12

Tags: swift-playground, xcode12

I use playgrounds in a framework project. Sometimes, there were build issues, which always disappeared after building the library.

After updating to Xcode 12, I cannot run the playgrounds anymore.

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport
import MyFramework

// Error: No such module `MyFramework`
```

Comment: same issue with my old & new playgrounds
and spotlight crash

Answer (score 15):

Select the playground. In the **Playground Settings** check the **Build Active Scheme** checkbox.

[image: Build Active Scheme]

**Note:** In Xcode 12.0 you need to change something in the playground code, in order to really trigger the change and see it in Git.

[image]

Comment: thanks, about change enough to save the playground file without any change.